# Slice array when element reached

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, slice

Lets say I have an array like so:
`['x','cat', 'dog', 'x', 'dolphin', 'cougar', 'whale']`

I don't know the length of the array or when an 'x' will occur. When I reach 'x' I want to push the following elements into a new array until I reach the next element that `includes?('x')`.

The desired output would be:
`[['cat', 'dog']['dolphin','cougar', 'whale']]`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Ahh the beloved SO 'What have you tried so far?'.

Tried a lot but it hasn't got me far... Don't know how to solve this one. IM STUCK :(

Comment: What if there are two `'x'` in a row or it ends on `'x'`? What's the behavior? Ignore or have an empty `[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good old [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) is handy for so many things:

```ruby
def split_array_by_item(array, item)
  array.reduce([]) do |memo, x|
    memo.push([]) if (x == item) || memo.empty?
    memo[-1].push(x) unless x == item
    memo
  end
end

a = ['x', 'cat', 'dog', 'x', 'dolphin', 'cougar', 'whale'] 
split_array_by_item(a, 'x') # => [["cat", "dog"], ["dolphin", "cougar", "whale"]]
```

**[Edit]** Also:

```ruby
def split_array_by_item(array, item)
  array.chunk{|x|x==item}.reject(&:first).map(&:last)
end
```

Comment: @Snarf I answered, can I have one too?

Answer (score 7):

[`Enumerable#slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) makes this simple:

```
a = ['x','cat', 'dog', 'x', 'dolphin', 'cougar', 'whale']
a.slice_before(/\Ax\z/).map { |chunk| chunk.drop(1) }
=> [["cat", "dog"], ["dolphin", "cougar", "whale"]]
```

Comment: +1, I was hoping someone would mention `slice_before`. It's made for exactly this situation.

Answer (score 3):

```
ar =  ['x', 'cat', 'dog', 'x', 'dolphin', 'cougar', 'whale']
p ar.chunk{|el| el == 'x'}.each_slice(2).map{|el| el.last.last}
#=> [["cat", "dog"], ["dolphin", "cougar", "whale"]]
```

Most of the work is chopping off the unneeded side results of the `chunk` method.

Answer (score 3):

[`Enumerable#chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) is the way to go. You can use `nil` to drop those chunks you don't want:

```
arr = ['x','cat', 'dog', 'x', 'dolphin', 'cougar', 'whale']

arr.chunk{ |e| e != 'x' || nil }.map(&:last)
#=> [["cat", "dog"], ["dolphin", "cougar", "whale"]]
```

Comment: Cool.  And this is equivalent: `arr.chunk{ |e| true if e != 'x' }.map(&:last)`  And you could replace `true` with any truthy.

Comment: This version works and it is very explicit:  `arr.chunk{ |e| e == 'x' ? :_separator : :payload }.map(&:last)`

Answer (score 0):

Since Ruby 2.0, a nice solution is **[slice_before](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before)** method or since 2.2 **[slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when)** method  :

We however need to *drop* the first element 'x' for each array generated :

```
ary =  ['x', 'cat', 'dog', 'x', 'dolphin', 'cougar', 'whale']

ary.slice_before{|e| e=='x'}.map{|t| t.drop(1)}

#==> [["cat", "dog"], ["dolphin", "cougar", "whale"]]

ary.slice_when{|i,j| j=='x'}.map{|t| t.drop(1)}

#==> [["cat", "dog"], ["dolphin", "cougar", "whale"]]
```